# Not able to access multiple tables from CGridView

Tags: database, yii, cgridview

I am facing a problem when i am trying to present the data from multiple database tables in a single CGridView in yii.

I have searched and referred enough number of articles on this. But i am not able to solve my problem.

I have 2 tables name user_master and customer_master. For each customer there will be a master record in user_master too.  tables are as follows -

> **user_master -** user_id, name, email_id, status 
>   **customer_master** - customer_id, user_id, account_type, creation_date, status

In UserMaster.php, the code is...

```
<?php
public function relations()
{
return array('customer_master'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'CustomerMaster', 'user_id'),);
}
public function searchUsers()
{
public $user_type;
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->alias = 't';
$criteria->compare('t.user_id',$this->user_id);
$criteria->compare('t.name',$this->name,true);
$criteria->compare('t.email_id',$this->email_id,true);
$criteria->compare('t.status',$this->status);

$criteria->together = true; 
$criteria->with = array('customer_master');
$criteria->compare('customer_master.user_id',$this->user_id,true);
$criteria->compare('customer_master.user_type',$this->user_type,true);

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array('criteria'=>$criteria, 
            'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>'user_id ASC',),));
}
?>
```

And in CustomerMaster.php...

```
<?php
public function relations()
{
return array('user_id' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'UserMaster', 'user_id'),);
} ?>
```

UserMasterController.php has the code as follows..

```
<?php
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new UserMaster('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['UserMaster']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['UserMaster'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model, ));
}
?>
```

In userMaster/admin.php

```
<?php

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-master-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->searchUsers(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'status',
                'email_id',
        array(
            'name' => 'customer_master.user_type',
                        //'header' => 'customer_master.user_type',
            **'value' => $data->customer_master->user_type,**
                     ),

        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

By calling the userMaster/admin page i am getting **Undefined variable: data**.

Please anyone help me out in solving this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'value' => '$data->customer_master->user_type',  // as a string!
```

*Value* is a string, to be evaluated as a PHP expression...

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now i am getting a new error. "Trying to get property of non-object"
..\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(606) : eval()'d code(1)

Comment: 'value' => '($data->getRelated(\'customer_master\')=== null)?\'No related customer registry\':$data->getRelated(\'customer_master\')->user_type',

this saved my life... its working now... it was bcz of the data problem in my DB.